# Facebook Unity SDK Invitable_friends API Issue

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, canvas, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Facebook unity SDK. I recently upgraded the unity SDK. Now, If I want to get invitable friends data. My app should be game and must contain canvas presence (Ref : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.0?locale=en_GB
). My game is mobile based (iOS/Android). I don’t have canvas app. But to use invitable_friends API, I had to provide dummy URL of the canvas app in facebook developer app settings. I read it some where on the internet so that I can access invitable_friends data. Now, it works fine. But I am now thinking, that is it right to use by above method. Can this thing be of some problem  (my app is already LIVE on app store). Should I create canvas app as well?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should.
Right now you can send see the invitable friends, but sending an app request using token to someone who is not a developper/tester/admin will fail. In order to use the tokens you need to submit the app for a review, and facebook won't approve this permission without an active game in canvas.

Comment: well I found a comment somewhere in the facebook blogs, where a developer stated that, you can simply put a placeholder in the canvas that tells you the app is available on the mobile store, and that's all...so you "may" skip the real canvas version....